# Seemingly simple import module case not compiling with 'namespace never provided' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-closure-compiler, ramda.js

I'm trying to get the [Ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda) library to work with closure compiler's advanced compilation mode.

It uses many small modules imported in the main [index.js](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/index.js).

This is the error I get:

```
$ closure-compiler --flagfile closure.conf --debug --formatting PRETTY_PRINT
src/main.js:1: ERROR - required "module$node_modules$ramda$index" namespace never provided
import R from 'ramda';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My `src/main.js` file is simply:

```
import R from 'ramda';

var greet = R.replace('{name}', R.__, 'Hello, {name}!');

const result = greet('Alice'); //=> 'Hello, Alice!'
console.log(result)
```

My `closure.conf` is

```
--compilation_level=ADVANCED
--js_output_file=out.js

--warning_level=QUIET
--dependency_mode=STRICT

--module_resolution=NODE

--process_common_js_modules

--js node_modules/ramda/src/**.js
--js node_modules/ramda/index.js

--js src/main.js

--js_module_root=node_modules

--entry_point=src/main
```

I have ramda installed via npm in node_modules:

```
$ tree node_modules -L 2
node_modules
├── ramda/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── src/
│   ├── CHANGELOG.md
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── LICENSE.txt
│   ├── package.json
│   └── README.md
└── .yarn-integrity
```

Closure Compiler Version: v20170910

---

What I don't understand is the `required "module$node_modules$ramda$index" namespace never provided` error message.

I have definitely provided the node_modules/ramda/index.js path as you can plainly see in the closure conf file.

1. What's with the 'module' prefix in the error message?
2. Why can't closure compiler resolve the module location?

---

**Edit:**

According to this PR/bug this might be an existing bug in closure-compiler: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/2641

To test out the fix I checked out the master branch and merged the proposed PR and created a new build.

This indeed takes me past the error message described above.

Also at @Scott Sauyet's suggestion in the comments I modified the import in `src/main.js` to be:

import * as R from 'ramda';

However there is another error message now.

```
$ closure-compiler --flagfile closure.conf --debug --formatting PRETTY_PRINT
src/main.js:3: ERROR - variable module$node_modules$ramda$index is undeclared
const greet = R.replace('{name}', R.__, 'Hello, {name}!');
      ^
```

This error occurrs regardless of whether the import is `* as R` or just `R`.

Comment: I don't know Closure Compiler well anymore, but Ramda does not export an `R`.  Would this do it?: `import * as R from 'ramda'`?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Updated the original text to reflect that change.